Copying all files/subdirectories from a directory contained within a jar whilst perserving directory structure
I'm trying to copy a folder and its subdirectories during runtime out of a jar.
My current approach is using PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver in the following way;
var resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
var resources = resolver.getResources("path/to/folder/**);
for (var resource: resources) {
   Files.copy(resources.getInputStream(), destinationDirectory.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}

Now this is fine but I have not found a way to perserve the original directory structure as everything now gets copied to the same level in my destinationDirectory.
